# Mapping from $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z \times \dots\times \mathbb Z/p_n\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Z/p_n\#\mathbb Z$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

I know $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z \times \dots\times \mathbb Z/p_n\mathbb Z$ is isomorphic $\mathbb Z/p_n\#\mathbb Z$ (where $p_n\#$ is the primorial of primes up to $p_n$) by the Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Groups, and I know the mapping from $\mathbb Z/p_n\#\mathbb Z$ to the product is $f(x) = (x\bmod2, x\bmod 3, x\bmod5, \dots,x\bmod{p_n})$. (Is there a good reference for this?) Since the product and $\mathbb Z/p_n\#\mathbb Z$ are isomorphic, the mapping in the reverse direction (from the product to $\mathbb Z/p_n\#\mathbb Z$) certainly exists. Is it known? I have figured out a formula - which I believe I can prove is correct - and am wondering if it might be worth writing this up as a paper.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $$N = \prod_{i=1}^j p_i^{e_i}$$ let $$c_i \frac{N}{p_i^{e_i}} \equiv 1 \bmod p_i^{e_i}$$ then

$$(a_1,\ldots,a_j) \mapsto \sum_{i=1}^j a_i \frac{N}{p_i^{e_i}} c_i$$ is the unique isomorphism $$\prod_{i=1}^j \Bbb{Z}/p_i^{e_i}\Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{Z}/N\Bbb{Z}$$ whose inverse is $$m \mapsto (m \bmod p_1^{e_1}, \ldots,m \bmod p_j^{e_j})$$

Comment: This is what we learn from CRT. Maybe the OP wants to show us  his "formula".

Comment: As usual I wanted to make this a comment but I realized it was the answer. With $N = \# p_n$ there is an induction formula for $c_i$, in general we can use $(N/p_i^{e_i})^{\varphi(p_i^{e_i})} \equiv 1\bmod p_i^{e_i}$ so $c_i = (N/p_i^{e_i})^{\varphi(p_i^{e_i})-1}$ , otherwise I don't see

Comment: My solution is equivalent to this - except I sum from 2 to j multiplying by $(a_i-1)$ rather than $a_i$ and add a constant 1 in place of the $i=1$ term. So - the answer to my question is, yes it's well known, and no this is not worth writing up. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That is exactly the statement of the [Chinese remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

Of course, if you found a specialized formula that is easier to calculate, or has some peculiarity, you can write that up. We will be looking forward to that.

Comment: The Chinese remainder theorem is the mapping from  $Z$ to the product group. I'm asking about the inverse and what I'm saying is that in the specific case of a primorial ${p_n}\#$, I have a function $f(v_1,v_2,\dots, v_n)$ that computes an integer $x$ which is a member of $Z/{p_n}\#Z$ given an n-tuple from the product $Z/2Z \times Z/3Z \times \dots Z/{p_n}Z$.

Comment: Apparently you have only learnt one half of CRT. The full statement of it involves a specified **isomorphism** $\mathbb Z/N\mathbb Z\cong \prod_{p_i^{\nu_i}\|N}\mathbb Z/p_i^{\nu_i}\mathbb Z$.

Comment: In fact, traditionally CRT is the term used for exactly what you asked for, instead of its inverse.

Comment: got it, thank you. So, by CRT, given an n-tuple from the product a unique $x$ in $Z$ exists and can be individually computed from the n-tuple using a variety of methods. The function I'm talking about can be constructed once (from the n primes) and then used to compute $x$ for any member of the product with n multiplications (summed, modulo the primorial). Is this interesting? I'm clearly an amateur in this area and greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: Actually, some proofs of the CRT give an explicit formula, and it is in quite a neat form already. So I really doubt your formula's utility. Anyway, without actually seeing the formula, nobody can decide :)

Comment: It's equivalent to the answer provided by user reuns - very slightly optimized for the case where his/her N is a primorial.